# WordPress deployment issue, how can we solve?

Tags: wordpress, deployment, web-deployment, wpbakery

I have two domain (pro and dev), which is deployed the same git repo for WP

The real pain is, since I am using the WPBakery for building pages, its storing the full URL of images and other files etc. when I deploy the website to pro I had to replace all the domain url by manually editing the sql file.

I was working with Drupal before and I Don't find any issue to deploy or swap environment such as WP.  so the question is, what is the right deployment strategy for WP ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since I coulden't find a way to use relative image urls, one sketchy solution that comes to my mind is finding the hook that filters all the VC output and use a simple search+replace rule on fly after checking the deployment environment.
something like:

```
add_filter('the_visualcomposer_hook_name', function($content){
    if( $is_example_server ){
        $content = str_replace( 'http://localhost/', 'http://example.com/', $content );
    }
}
```

You can also do this by filtering `the_content` if you visual composer is run in `the_content()`.